# Unable to send json string containing encoded string with curl in php

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, curl, encode

I have created a script to send json data to a url

```
$data   =   array();

$key        =   'mysecretkey';
$string     =   'teststring';

$data['date']               =   '2013-06-19 05:38:00';
$data['encrypted_string']   =   mcrypt_encode($string,$key);
$data['id']                 =   231;
$data['source_ref']         =   'testreference';
$data['status']             =   'Active';

header('Content-type: text/json');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$url = 'http://localhost/myproject/test/add_json_data'; 

$json_string    =   json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json_string);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

`mcrypt_encode` encodes the string. Here is the json_string

```
{
  "date": "2013-06-19 05:38:00",
  "encrypted_string": "7Y4jqgIfhj25ghsF8yJ/qTtzXafTtIlwsz7xWIDVWJGoF22X2JbfSWfQtgmI1dYyyJDgs3nmaWctTEgKW5VmHw==",
  "id": 231,
  "source_ref": "testreference",
  "status": "Active"
}
```

When i exe4cute the script nothing happens on the url i provided.

Here is what i am doing on the url.

```
function add_json_data()
{
    $json   =   file_get_contents('php://input');

    $obj        =   json_decode($json);

    $this->load->helper('file');
    write_file('json.json',$json);      
}
```

I am using codeigniter so i am simply saving the post data in a file in json format to see what is coming. But i see the url is not called. I assume due to the encoded json string which contains encoded string it is not sending data to url. How can i send my encoded key to the url. I have also checked if i replace `encrypted_string` with something 'test' it is working fine. How can i send data to the url or any alternative? Please help.

Comment: Do you have the mcrypt php module enabled? Perhaps your calling an undefined function with error reporting turned off? Your code works fine on my local...

Comment: i don't understand what you mean. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Always turn on `error_reporting` when you're developing code, otherwise the simplest syntax error looks like a showstopping bug.

The line:

```
$string     =   'teststring'
```

Is missing a semicolon.

Comment: sorry i have corrected it. It is not the matter of semicolon or i would not be able to display json output

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for this. Here is how i can do this

```
$data   =   array();

$key        =   'mysecretkey';
$string     =   'teststring';

$data['date']               =   '2013-06-19 05:38:00';
$data['encrypted_string']   =   mcrypt_encode($string,$key);
$data['id']                 =   231;
$data['source_ref']         =   'testreference';
$data['status']             =   'Active';

$url = 'http://localhost/myproject/test/add_json_data'; 

$json_string    =   json_encode($data);

$header[]   =   'Content-type: text/json';
$header[]   =   'Content-type: application/json';
$header[]   =   'Content-Length: '.strlen($json_string);

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json_string);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

After setting header array and passing it to curl as an option it is working fine.